# Find unique identifier between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, fetch

After I do a fetch to a endpoint using the Fetch API, my response consists out of an object housing 2 arrays that looks something like this.

`{games_list: Array(192), owner_list: Array(4)}`

In each array there is a unique identifier that both arrays share *e.g.* `node_id`

I need a way retrieve all games that one unique owner has so at the end I will have a list of the 4 owners and how many games each owner has *(hope this makes sense)*

So far all I got is the following:

```
const getData = () => {
  fetch('./data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data) // all data

      const allGames = data.games_list
      const allOwners = data.owner_list

      // Get all id's for games_list and owner_list
      const gameNodeIds = allGames.map(id => id.node_id)
      const ownerNodeIds = allOwners.map(id => id.node_id)
    })
    .catch(err =>  console.error(`Error: ${err}`))
}
```

**Example of the data returned:**

```
{
  "games_list": [
    {
      "game": "Overwatch",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ],
  .....
  "owners_list": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is as far as I got, I really need some help moving forward from here so all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you replace `Array(xx)` with a few examples?

Comment: I updated my description @GetOffMyLawn

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `map()` and `filter()` to return the desired result with the desired structure

See code snippet

```js
var data = {
  "games_list": [
    {
      "game": "game1",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "1"
    },
     {
      "game": "game2",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "1"
    },
     {
      "game": "game3",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "2"
    }
  ],

  "owners_list": [
    {
      "name": "owner 1",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "owner 2",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "owner 3",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "3"
    }
   
  ]
}

const allGames = data.games_list;
const allOwners = data.owners_list;


var result = allOwners.map(owner => 
  ({owner: owner.name,
    games:allGames.filter(game => game.node_id === owner.node_id
  ).length 
  })
)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to find how many times your specific node_id exists in allGames?

```
var games_by_owner = {};
allOwners.forEach(function(ele, idx){
   gameNoeIds.forEach(function(eleG, idxG){
       if(typeof games_by_owner[idx] == 'undefined') {
           games_by_owner[idx] = [];
       }

       if (ele.node_id == eleG.node_id) {      
           games_by_owner[idx].push(idxG);
       }
   });
});
```

So you will collect for every Owner idx array of his Games idxG.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object or Map and the common key value as properties to create a `counts` object

Following assumes that some games may not have owners in the owners list and you only want counts for existing owners

```js
let data = {
  "games_list": [
    {
      "game": "Overwatch",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ],
  
  "owners_list": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ]
}
let ownerCounts = data.owners_list.reduce((a,c)=> (a[c.node_id]=0,a),{});
data.games_list.forEach(g=> g.node_id in ownerCounts && ownerCounts[g.node_id]++);

console.log(ownerCounts)
```

If not worried that game owner is in game owner list you only have to loop over the games list

```js
let data = {
  "games_list": [
    {
      "game": "Overwatch",
      "game_type": "Shooter",
      "developers": "Blizzard",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ],
  
  "owners_list": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "25",
      "Occupation": "gamer",
      "node_id": "123456778"
    }
  ]
}
let ownerCounts = data.games_list.reduce((a,c)=> (a[c.node_id]= (a[c.node_id]||0)+1,a),{});


console.log(ownerCounts)
```